# Problems with Shiny app (no graph displayed for given inputs)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

This is a dput of my `data.frame` (first 25 rows from a total of 2646)

```
dput(delitos)
    structure(list(fecha = structure(c(17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 
    17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17909, 
    17910, 17911, 17912, 17913, 17914, 17915, 17916, 17917, 17918, 
    17919, 17920, 17921), class = "Date"), tipo = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("sv", "cv", "tot"
    ), class = "factor"), n = c(4, 6, 15, 22, 5, 1, 10, 8, 15, 11, 
    20, 4, 5, 14, 5, 13, 10, 10, 7, 2, 10, 6, 11, 16, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to do a shiny app which displays a graph line based on two criteria: `fecha` and `tipo` (both variables on my `data.frame`). Below the code so far (please don't care about my comments in spanish):

```
library(shiny)        # Librería principal
library(tidyverse)    # Manipulación de datos
library(bslib)        # Modificación de temas
library(thematic)     # Ajuste del tema con el plot

thematic::thematic_shiny(font = "auto")

ui <- fluidPage( 

      theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty",
                       heading_font = font_google("Work Sans"),
                       base_font = font_google("Work Sans"),
                       code_font = font_google("Space Mono")
                       ),

  titlePanel(
    h4(strong("Robos, 2019-2021"))),    
    sidebarPanel(
    
              dateRangeInput("fecha", "Fecha", 
                    start= "2019-01-01", end= "2021-05-31", format= "dd/mm/yyyy",
                    separator="-", language= "es"
                     ),
              
    # Caja para seleccionar entre opciones
              checkboxGroupInput("tipo", 
                       "Tipo", 
                       choices = list("Con violencia" = "cv", 
                                      "Sin violencia" = "sv", 
                                      "Total" = "tot"),
                       selected = "tot")
              
              
    ),   
      
    # Creación de panel donde se colocará el output principal (default lado derecho)
    mainPanel(   # Aquí se puede agregar un título
                    plotOutput("robos")

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive( {
    dplyr::filter(delitos, 
                dplyr::between(fecha, base::as.Date(input$fecha[1], 
                format="%d/%m/%Y"),base::as.Date(input$fecha[2],
                format="%d/%m/%Y")) & 
                tipo%in%input$tipo)}
  )
  
  output$robos <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data(), 
    aes(x=fecha, y=n, color=tipo, fill=tipo)) +
    geom_line(size=1.2) +
    xlim(-1.5,1.5) +
    xlab("Fecha") +
    ylab("Robos") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","red", "pink"))+
    scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red","pink")) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Everything seems fine to me but when I run the app I get the following error depending on my `input$tipo` selection:

```
Warning: Removed 882 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path)
Warning: Removed 1764 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
Warning: Removed 2646 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

Because of that, no line is displayed no matter what criteria I choose. Honestly I don't know where the error is so I'll appreciate any feedback and suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is that you set the `xlim` to `c(-1.5, 1.5)` which seems odd when dealing with dates.

Comment: OMG, you're right! I copypasted the basic code from other graph and didn't look at that detail. Thanks for this, man.